# Why is <ROOT> showing in my XML via SSIS/C#?

Tags: xml, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a scalar function like below

```
CREATE FUNCTION Logging.ParentDataSourceStatus
(
    @ParentDataSourceKey INT
)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
    @Xml XML

SET
@Xml = (
    SELECT
        ExecutionStatus.ExecutionStatus
    ,   ParentDataSourceSummary.TotalErrorRows

    FROM
        Logging.ParentDataSourceSummary
        JOIN Logging.ExecutionStatus
            ON ParentDataSourceSummary.ParentDataSourceStatus = ExecutionStatus.ExecutionStatusCode

    WHERE
        ParentDataSourceSummary.ParentDataSourceKey = @ParentDataSourceKey

    FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT ('ParentDataSourceStatus')
)
RETURN @Xml
END
```

Which returns the following XML when I query it in SSMS

```
<ParentDataSourceStatus>
  <ExecutionStatus>Complete</ExecutionStatus>
  <TotalErrorRows>0</TotalErrorRows>
</ParentDataSourceStatus>
```

I am using this function in an execute SQL task in an SSIS package using XML as the returned result set via an ADO.NET connection with the statement:

`SELECT Logging.ParentDataSourceStatus(1614)`

The returned result is stored in a variable of type object. When I read this variable in a script task like so:

```
XmlDocument xml = (XmlDocument)Dts.Variables["User::ParentDataSourceStatus"].Value;
```

The debugger shows the InnerXml as follows:

```
<ROOT>
  <ParentDataSourceStatus>
    <ExecutionStatus>Complete</ExecutionStatus>
    <TotalErrorRows>0</TotalErrorRows>
  </ParentDataSourceStatus>
</ROOT>
```

I've already named the root element in the function so where is `<ROOT>` being added and can I get rid of it?

Comment: How are you calling this? I'm pretty sure, that the code you show will not add a `<ROOT>` out of nowhere...

Comment: SQL statement via ADO.NET connection example `SELECT Logging.ParentDataSourceStatus(1614)`

Comment: Just try to call this from SSMS, there will be no `<ROOT>`. It seems, that there is a Schema involved? Try to read - just for testing - this function into a string variable. As said before: I'm quite sure, that the `<ROOT>` is coming from somewhere else...

Comment: In SSMS I see no `<ROOT>` in the XML or when casting it to `VARCHAR(MAX)`. If I perform this cast in my execute SQL task and store the result to a string variable and then convert it to `XmlDocument` in my script there is no `<ROOT>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that when returning an XML result set from the Execute SQL Task it is adding the result into a `<ROOT></ROOT>` node.

There is no option to disable this and the returned result in XML would have to be manipulated further to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate a bit your code to following, with replace :

```
string content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" + Dts.Variables["User::DataXML"].Value.ToString().Replace("<ROOT>", "").Replace("</ROOT>", "");
```

(i am adding and the encoding of xml file on the begging as well)